# Cleaner way to have params with Rails and JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ember.js, json-api

I have an Ember application for client side and Rails for server side. I decided to use json-api because I think it is a standard for both. When I save a model, Ember send this kind of data :

```
{ "data" =>
  { "relationships" =>
    { "users" =>
      { "data" =>
        [ { "type" => "users", "id" => "2" } ]
      }
    },
    "type" => "trails"
  },
  "controller" => "api/v1/trails",
  "action" => "create"
}
```

In my controller, I have this method :

```
  def create
    render json: Trail.create(trail_params)
  end
```

I can obviously do a method `trail_params` that change parameters and return the format used by ActiveRecord but I want to know if their is a better way.

I use ActiveModelSerializer but I don't see a built-in solution.

**My problem** : I don't like the fact than I have to do a parser to deserialize parameters and to have `{users: [2]}` as ActiveRecord want.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What problem are you trying to solve? You say you want a "cleaner way"—what part of your existing implementation is "unclean"?

Comment: Your approach is good and clean.

Comment: @Jordan I edited my question. I'm looking for a way to have the ActiveRecord's format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little late, but...

You're right that JSON API support isn't yet built into Rails' AMS. However, there are a few Ruby libraries out there that make it really easy to build JSON API-compliant APIs on top of ActiveRecord. Perhaps the best is [JSONAPI::Resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources), but there's also [Oat](https://github.com/ismasan/oat) and, [very soon](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/950) a different AMS library.

Answer (score 1):

the data format you posted here is determined by Ember's serialization layer. You use json-api. The format though does not fit to Active Record. So json-api isn't a standard for both. I used Ember's layer [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data): it works with AR perfectly out-of-the-box

Comment: I use Ember Data with JSONAPIAdapter. As shown in [this post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html) "In Ember Data 2.0 the default adapter will be the JSONAPIAdapter.". I find it easier for associations.

Answer (score 0):

My problem will be resolved by [this pull request](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/950). It accepts the JSON api format and convert it to ActiveRecord's format.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [jsonapi-utils](https://github.com/b2beauty/jsonapi-utils) gem that brings a simple way to render JSON API-compliant responses:

You would write something like this:

```
class API::UsersController < API::BaseController
  def index
    jsonapi_render json: User.all
  end
end
```

You will find more examples in its official documentation. Hope it helps.